# MySQLdb execute INSERT to table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am new to MySql and MySQLdb. But i have tried for hours to solve this problem.

I have a table like this:

> mysql> DESCRIBE users;

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

the code part:

```
def connect_db():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='root',
                            passwd='',
                            db='flask',
                            host='localhost')
    return conn


cur = connect_db().cursor()


cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE users(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \
                username VARCHAR(25), password VARCHAR(25))")

str = "INSERT INTO users ('id', 'username', 'password') VALUES (NULL, %s, %s)"

cur.execute(str % ('admin', 'password'))
```

I got an error like this:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Emil\Desktop\flaskr\flaskr.py", line 29, in <module>
>     cur.execute(str % ('admin', 'password'))   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in
> execute
>     self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in
> defa lterrorhandler
>     raise errorclass, errorvalue
> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL synta ; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right yntax to use near ''id', 'username', 'password')
> VALUES (NULL, admin, password)  at line 1")
```

I guess it's something wrong with my INSERT command. I have no idea what to do and have tried searching for content that may help on google.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the resulting query you would get with your current solution:

```
INSERT INTO users ('id', 'username', 'password') VALUES (NULL, admin, password)
```

As you see, no quotes around `admin` and `password` - this is the reason for the `ProgrammingError` exception.

Aside from that, inserting query parameters via string formatting makes your code *vulnerable to SQL injections*.

---

Instead, **parameterize the query**:

```
query = """
    INSERT INTO 
        users 
        ('id', 'username', 'password') 
    VALUES 
        (NULL, %s, %s)
"""

cur.execute(query, ('admin', 'password'))
```